# How locate Windows process creation calls in disassembled code?

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I have program that that calls another CLI program, no source code for either of the programs.
I was wondering with which parameters the first program is calling the command line program.

Using Sysinternals Process Explorer I was able to find out the parameters. One of them was a weird looking string. Being curious, I wanted to know where the originates: what kind of variables is it dependent on or whether it is hard-coded.

The string was not present in ASCII form. So, I wanted to actually find out where the CLI application was being called, so I could dig deeper. Unfortunately, this was where I got stuck. 
I do not know much about Windows API and how processes are created. I cannot find the part where the CLI application process is being created. I tried using a tool called StraceNT but I could not find the calls anywhere (I assumed it would be using the `CreateProcess()` functions).

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but it just seemed interesting. Any suggested reading as to educate myself is welcome.

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint on NtCreateProcess.

Comment: Not much to go on, but there's several `CreateProcess` variants to check out. You've tagged OllyDbg so, Alt+E for the module list, find `kernel32`, and Ctrl+N for the names. F2 (breakpoint) on `CreateProcessA`, `CreateProcessW` (unicode), `CreateProcessAsUserW` and the other CreateProcess* exports. If it doesn't use one of these to invoke *something* then try `ntdll` and the `ZwCreateProcess`* functions. There are other ways to create process, and they're all more *fun* to debug. Let me know how you get on with these first.

Comment: @Leigh: If you're using OllyDbg, you can just do Ctrl+G I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx). Add a filter `Operation` `begins with` `Process` if you want to see process creation/termination activity only. It will then be logged when a process is created, including what created it.

You can then double-click the "Process Create" event you are interested in, and look at the tab "Stack". Voilà, you get a call stack showing you how the process creation was initiated!

Here I started notepad from explorer:

[image]